# Correct scaling of the ordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib

maybe you could help me further.
I wanted to visualize my CSV data with Matplotlib.
I have attached the code below.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Mount the Google Drive to access the CSV files
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
# Define the path to the CSV files
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/CSV_Files/"

# Get the list of all CSV files in the path
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

# Loop through each CSV file and plot columns e1 and e2 against column zt
for file in csv_files:
  # Load the CSV file into a DataFrame
  df = pd.read_csv(path + file, sep=";")
  
  # Plot columns e1 and e2 against column zt
  plt.plot(df['zt'], df['e1'], label='e1')
  plt.plot(df['zt'], df['e2'], label='e2')
  plt.title(file[:-4]) # Set the title to the filename without the .csv extension
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the code does not behave as I expected. The ordinate (y-axis) is scaled incorrectly and the values are stacked. Also, my data is displayed linearly, even though the data should describe an S-curve. In Excel it is also displayed, only in Matplotlib it is linear. Do you have a tip, what am I doing wrong? I attach a picture of the diagram:
[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJJIs.png)

Comment: Make sure you are reading the data as numbers (floats) instead of strings.

Comment: Also, it is easier to help you if you provide a minimum data sample to reproduce your issue

Comment: Thank you Photon and Romain! The problem was really the data type as Photon described.

Comment: @ThePhoton Can you please post your answer than I can vote this as an solution. If you want :)